# Typcasting json to class angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been following a few tutorials around the net, and have come to the conclusion that if my Angular 2 application calls a rest endpoint, I can automatically map the result to an interface or to a class I define. Hence, I am attempting to do the latter. Here is some sample json that I am working with:

```
{
  "StudentResponse": {
    "haveProblems": false,
    "students": [
      {
        "id": "55",
        "name": "Joel"
      },
      {
        "id": "56",
        "name": "Anderson"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here are the two classes I am attempting to construct. First, this is my main response wrapper.

```
import {Students} from "./Students";

export class StudentResponse {

    haveProblems: boolean;
    students: Student[];

    constructor(json: any) {
        console.log("### we are in the main response constructor");
        this.haveProblems = json.StudentResponse.haveProblems;
        if(json.StudentResponse.students && this.haveProblems != true) {
            this.students = json.StudentResponse.students.map((student) => new Student(student));
        }
    }
}
```

This is a child within the main response wrapper.

```
export class Student {

    id: string;
    name: string;

    constructor(student: any) {
        if (student) {
            this.id = student.id;
            this.name = student.name;
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the mapping to this type in the following GET Rest call:

```
private getStudents(url: string): StudentResponse {
    return this._http.get(url, getOptions())
        .map(res => <StudentResponse>res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

I have noticed that the console statement in my StudentResponse class is never invoked. However, If I add an anonymous function in the map method, I can parse the json and create a new StudentResponse manually. Obviously, I want to make this easier for myself, and let angular do it. I wish I still had the link to the article, but I am hoping someone else can chime in and point out the issues in my typecasting here.

**Additional things tried with comments that did not work:**

```
constructor(res: Response) {
    console.log("### we are in the constructor");
    let json = res.json();
    ...
}

// map the rest response
.map(res => new StudentResponse(res))
```

Comment: to call the constructor you might need to change it to `.map(res => new StudentResponse(res.json())`.

Comment: @AlexSzabó just tried it, no cigar :/

Comment: But @AlexSzabó is right - that's the only way, the constructor gets called. Otherwise you're just "casting" which has no meaning in the compiled JS anyway.

Comment: @rinukkusu I am certainly not saying he is wrong. I am just stating that the constructor is not being called.

Comment: try mapping the result inside of the constructor of your class after invoking it the way @AlexSzabó specified..

Comment: Are you subscribing to the `getStudents` method?

Comment: @rinukkusu I am. In addition, if I make an anonymous function in the .map to parse the json and then create a new StudentResponse, everything is fine. However, I should not have to do all that work.

Comment: @gkb I do not think I understand your reccomendation. Are you stating that I should pass the response to my constructor, and then inside of it, parse the json?

Comment: @gkb hmm still no luck. I updated the question with how I attempted it.

Comment: @angryip - just a wild guess, why don't you try initializing your students array to a default student object along with the declaration inside of the StudentResponse class?

Comment: @AlexSzabó for some unknown reason, I bounced npm, and all is working as you stated. Please post as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @angryip I'm glad it helped, but also props to others who've helped.

Comment: agreed. I thank you all for your help.

Comment: your Student class should actually look like this:
`export class Student {
      constructor(public id: number, public name:string) {}
    }`

Comment: @AlexOkrushko any particular reason I should remove the properties? and remove the json constructor?

Comment: Your properties are created and initialized at the same time. `let student = new Student(0, 'Alex')` would give you `student.name === 'Alex'`. Scroll down to "Parameter properties" [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

To call the constructor you need to change it to

```
.map(res => new StudentResponse(res.json())
```